# Tutorial test for calculate average fails: output shouldn't contain: 0

Tags: java

i'm new here learning java and on the site that i'm learning on one of the tests i cannot pass because of this error

```
When input was:

>1  
2  
0  

output shouldn't contain:  
>0
```

the test is

> Write a program that asks the user for input until the user inputs 0. After this, the program prints the average of the positive numbers (numbers that are greater than zero).
>
> If no positive number is inputted, the program prints "Cannot calculate the average"

```java
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int inputs = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        double average = 0;
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Give a number:");
            int number = Integer.valueOf(scanner.nextLine());
            if (number > 0) {
                inputs++;
                sum += number;
                average = (double)sum / inputs;
                System.out.println(average);
            } else if (number <= 0) {
                System.out.println("Cannot calculate the average");
            }
            if (number == 0) {
                break;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should calculate and print average after all input has been given, that is after the `while` loop

Comment: To explain more, in the first loop, the program prints average "1.0", which contains a zero, which causes the test to fail. Expected output for "1 2 0" should only be "1.5"

Comment: Voting to close because it's simple debugging help, not a good question for others.

Answer (score 0):

Find what worked for me below:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AverageOfPositiveNumbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        //Task is to keep count of positive integers, sum and calculate average
        double pNumbers = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        //Task is to read user input and assign a variable 
        while (true) {
            //Task is to prompt user for input 
            System.out.println("Enter number:");
            int number = Integer.valueOf(scanner.nextLine());
            //Task is to terminate the program when user inputs 0
            if (number == 0) {
                break;
            }
            if (number > 0) {
                pNumbers = pNumbers + 1;
                sum = sum + number;
            }
        }
        //The task is to calculate the average 
        //print only if user has given numbers and avoid dividing by zero 
        if (sum + pNumbers > 0) {
            double average = (sum / pNumbers);
            System.out.println(average);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Cannot calculate the average");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: It's better to explain to the OP what is wrong with their code rather than to just give a slab of your code, even if it works.